# Проверить объекты в коллекции в цикле

Tags: java, android

Есть класс `SingleWord` с полями `String word`, `String alphabet`, `int icon`.
Есть коллекция `ArrayList<SingleWord>`, которая хранит объекты типа `SingleWord`. Как в цикле проверить, содержит ли переменная `word` каждого объекта коллекции слово `str`?

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно проверить, содержит ли `word` каждого элемента списка подстроку `"str"`, то можно так:

```
boolean contains = true;
for (SingleWord singleWord : words)
{
    if (!singleWord.word.contains("str"))
    {
        contains = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

При использовании Android SDK 24+:

```
boolean contains = words.stream().map(e -> e.word).allMatch(w -> w.contains("str"));
```

Comment: Стоит указать что этот способ будет работать только для приложений с minSdk > 23

Comment: @temq не заметил в вопросе метки "android". Тогда ответ вообще лучше удалить. А что - с SDK 24 в Android появилась поддержка Java 8?

Comment: Частичная поддержка появилась, в том числе и стримы

Answer (score 0):

```
List <SingleWorld> matches = new ArraList <>();
for(SingleWord word : words //твой лист){
   if(word.getWord().contains(str)
       matches.add(word)  //изменять коллекцию, которая перебирается в цикле нельзя
}
//здесь делай всё что хочешь с этими данными
```